# Assigning Static Resources to a Custom control

Tags: maui

In .NET MAUI, I have a custom control (Label), which could not be derived from Label itself as this did not work with the Bindings.

I then went for a ContentView which creates the Label in its constructor and assigns the Label.TextProperty as a Binding to the Property defined in this ContentView.

Before creating this custom control, I had a standard Label and had a Binding to the Text- and Style-Property. The Text-Property also has a Converter like this:

```xml
<Label Text=“{Binding ValueProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyValueConverter}}“ Style=“{StaticResource MyLabelStyle}“ />
```

Both of them worked before, but when I attached them to the custom control the Converter did not work anymore and the Style also could not be assigned to the Label.

I guess, it has a Problem with the static resource defined in a different view outside my custom control view.

Is this true and is there a way I can solve this?

==== Update of my Code ====

Originally, this should have been derived just from a Label, not a ContentView.

But, then I wanted to implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** which did not work correctly then with all kinds of Bindings I wanted to use. So, I tried it with a ContentView and a Lable inside:

```cs
public class CustomLabel : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(CustomLabel), string.Empty);
    

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }


    public CustomLabel()
    {
        var label = new Label();

        
        label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(nameof(Text), source: this, stringFormat: "  {0:C}")); // Adjust the format as needed


        // Try to determine Color "Gray900" defined in Colors.xaml
        Color gray = Colors.Gray;       // Default Color if the right one can't be found
        if (App.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("Gray900", out var colorvalue))
        {
            gray = (Color)colorvalue;
        }             

        Style labelStyle = new Style(typeof(Label));
        labelStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Label.FontSizeProperty, Value = 11 });
        labelStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = Label.TextColorProperty, Value = gray });
        label.Style = labelStyle;


        Content = label;
    }
}
```

**ContentViews in which I wanted to use this custom control:**

```xml
<ContentView.Resources>
    <!-- Database value Converter -->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:ValueDatabaseConverter x:Key="MacroValueDatabaseConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>

...

<SwipeView>
    
    <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">

        <StackLayout>
            
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, 60, 60, 70" Margin="0, 10, 0, 10">
            
                ...
            
                <HorizontalStackLayout HeightRequest="20">
                    <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        <Image Source="img1.png" HeightRequest="16" WidthRequest="16" Margin="2, -2, 3, 2" />
                        <Label Text="{loc:Translate Calculate_Item1LabelString, StringFormat='{0}:'}" Style="{StaticResource ItemSelectionDetailsLabelStyle}"/>
                        <!--<Label Text="{Binding Item.Powder, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ValueDatabaseConverter}, StringFormat='  {0:0.###}  '}" Style="{StaticResource ItemSelectionDetailsLabelStyle}"/>-->
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>

                    <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0">
                        <Image Source="img2.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" Margin="0, -5, 0, 0" />
                        <Label Text="{loc:Translate Calculate_Item2LabelString, StringFormat='{0}:'}" Style="{StaticResource ItemSelectionDetailsLabelStyle}"/>
                        <!--<Label Text="{Binding Item.Condense, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ValueDatabaseConverter}, StringFormat='  {0:0.###}  '}" Style="{StaticResource ItemSelectionDetailsLabelStyle}"/>-->
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>

                    <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0">
                        <Image Source="img3.png" HeightRequest="12" WidthRequest="12" Margin="5, -1, 5, 5"/>
                        <Label Text="{loc:Translate Calculate_Item3LabelString, StringFormat='{0}:'}" Style="{StaticResource ItemSelectionDetailsLabelStyle}"/>
                        <!--<Label Text="{Binding Item.Famity, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ValueDatabaseConverter}, StringFormat='  {0:0.###}  '}" Style="{StaticResource ItemSelectionDetailsLabelStyle}"/>-->
                        <labelControls:CustomLabel Text="{Binding Item.Famity, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ValueDatabaseConverter}" />
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>   

            </Grid>
            
        </StackLayout>
        
    </Border>
    
</SwipeView>
```

Comment: Please show the code of your custom control.

Comment: I edited my question and updated some code :)

Comment: @Julian - As described below in the comment to Peter, I'll give it up with this weird combination and stay with the proposed way using the Label as my base for the custom control

Answer (score 0):

In your `ContentView` you need to have defined it in the `Resources`

```xml
<ContentView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converter:MyValueConverter x:Key="MyValueConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted to build in some more flexibility as it is a Custom Control that could be used in different places (e.g. different ContentViews). So, I thought I could define these resources in these ContentViews and just provide them to my CustomControl

Comment: I think I'll give it up with this unnatural combination of Label inside a ContentView. I'll use the Label as base and don't use INotifyPropertyChanged so that it works as expected. The combination with a ContentView is too unnatural. Thanks anyway for your help